# Having A Squirrel as a pet

Tags: hadith, islamic-philosophy, halal-haram, pets, property

So Inshallah I will be Getting a Squirrel but I don't know if it is prohibited in Islam should I keep it in a cage or on a bed or nest do I have to keep it complete solitare from it's Family or if I buy it from far away should I still Inshallah get becuase rabbits you can not keep them from there family,or even keep a Squirrel in general.

Answer (score 2):

short answer no it is not prohibited but remember prophet Muhammed(pbuh)'s hadeeth (quote):
{A woman was punished because she imprisoned a cat until it died. On account of this, she was doomed to Hell. While she imprisoned it, she did not give the cat food or drink, nor did she free it to eat from the earth.}
also:
He also said that a man gave a very thirsty dog a drink, so God forgave his sins for this action. The Prophet was asked, “Messenger of God, are we rewarded for kindness towards animals?” He said: {There is a reward for kindness to every living animal or human.}
so if these animals can't live away from their families, you shouldn't buy them in order not to encourage the sellers to bring more of them :(
from that I prefer leaving these animals where they belong but if you insist I think it is better to buy it from far away rather than taking it from its family.

Comment: seeing how our prophet encouraged good treatment of all animals...what do u say when to say u see a dog and you know that the dog doesn't have a home to stay in or have its parents. And u know the streets isn't a good place for that dog....are you allowed to take the dog in? While keeping in mind of the classic restrictions given by scholars that keeping dogs as pet is haram?